# native messaging on linux does not work

Tags: linux, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I've been trying to run a Native Messaging on Debian Linux, but when I click the connect button, I only get the message "Connecting to native messaging host com.google.chrome.example.echo" and nothing else.

Everything is similar to the [default example](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/nativeMessaging/app.zip), I only changed the path at the manifest file. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It does work in **Chrome 35**, **Chromium 34** (from default depository) and Opera Developer on Ubuntu 14.04.

<strike>Though I couldn't get it working in **Opera Developer 24** (chromium 37)</strike>.
Opera just [fixed that](http://blogs.opera.com/desktop/changelog-24/#b1558.17). But broke it later again.

So take another look on your settings:

### Location of home manifest file:

```
~/.config/chromium/NativeMessagingHosts/
~/.config/google-chrome/NativeMessagingHosts/
~/.config/opera-developer/NativeMessagingHosts
```

### How to Debug

Start Chromium like:

```
chromium-browser --enable-logging --v=1
```

You will get an error message like this if the path is wrong:

```
ERROR:native_process_launcher.cc(131)] Can't find manifest for native messaging host com.google.chrome.example.echo
```

### Support

For any version of Chromium-version under 34 the userspace isn't supported, you need a CLI switch:

```
--native-messaging-hosts="com.google.chrome.example.echo=~/.config/chromium/NativeMessagingHosts/com.google.chrome.example.echo.json"
```

<strike>Also it didn't work in Opera-Developer 24 for me at the moment</strike>.